# Best way to prevent progressively slower row inserts as table grows in Grails

Tags: grails

I have a table in my Grails app that is growing rather large - 100,000 rows or so and it's growing by about 10,000 rows per day. I've noticed that inserts are getting progressively slower as the table grows. I assume this has to do with my indexes. What is the best way to address this?

Comment: Post your domain class and we might be able to help you (especially the `mapping` closure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes could be indexes, but often the biggest hit is because the hibernate session is bloated out, described well by [Ted Naleid](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql/) .  If this doesn't work for you tell us more about your situation are you doing bulk inserts or is it your site getting 10000 inserts from different requests etc?

I got around this by having a simple method that is called every so often as Ted suggests (eg every 1000 rows inserted)

```
def cleanUpGorm() {
        def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
        session.flush()
        session.clear()
        propertyInstanceMap.get().clear()
    }
```

Comment: You should clarify that this method only applies in the case of bulk inserts.

Answer (score 0):

You should first confirm whether it is a DB issue or Grails/Hibernate issue; I would start by outputting the SQL generated by Hibernate in `Datasource.groovy` and seeing if anything unusual is happening there. You could also use various SQL profiling tools provided by the DB vendor to see what is going on there; for example you could generate an `EXPLAIN PLAN` from the SQL to see whether inserts are slow due to not having the correct indexes.

When it comes to dealing with performance issues, you want to drill down and find concrete evidence of the cause, everything else would just be guessing.