# Why would a sql query hang when run a second time in a Java application?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, grails, groovy

Context: Grails 2.1, using Groovy SQL to execute SQL statements. Database is Oracle 11G running in a RedHat VM.  Grails is running in interactive mode, though running as WAR makes no difference in behavior.

Via Groovy SQL, I'm issuing a SQL statement with this structure:

```
insert into...
select ... from...
```

This results in @119K rows being fetched and inserted. When it runs successfully, it usually completes in under a minute.

This statement runs in the context of an entire data import application that typically takes about 10 minutes total to run and comprises many other queries.

Here's the behavior:

1. I start the Grails app
2. I kick off the data import in the application. It runs as expected and results in significant change to the data
3. I kick off the application again. The first few dozen queries run fine
4. At the larger insert mentioned above, it hangs.

So: first time through, no problems. Second time through, it hangs at the same place, every time.

If I restart the application, it'll run fine again.

Here's where it gets weird: I'll let this thing spin for a while, and if I shut off the database, the query keeps running. I get no error.

So, if this behavior sounds familiar, I'm interested in solutions.

If you have ideas on how to diagnose this, I'm interested in those, too. I'm an application developer and much more familiar with the Java side of the house than the Oracle side, fwiw. I'm trying to find an in-house Oracle DBA to assist, but at least for the near term I'm on my own.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Try running sqlplus and query the locks: http://www.shutdownabort.com/dbaqueries/Performance_Locks_DML.php

Comment: If all your statements are inserts, this can happen if two different transactions are inserting the **same** primary key values.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said a restart of the app makes it work again indicates its not anything on the SQL side such as indexes, so it could be related to Hibernate session size, you could be maxing out the session, [see this answer that may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558640/best-way-to-prevent-progressively-slower-row-inserts-as-table-grows-in-grails/12576483#12576483)